# How can I match a range between a line and the last occurrence of a pattern in `sed`?

Tags: sed, gnu

Is there a simple way to set up pattern range matching in `sed` to have the second pattern look for the last occurence in a file?

```sh
sed -r '1,/\[notice\]/d' /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

will spit out every line after the first `[notice]` pattern is found.  But it would be better if I could make so that it was the last `[notice]` pattern instead.

Comment: You can use `tac` to read the lines in reverse, pipe that to sed, and then pipe the result to `tac` again.

Comment: @ChristofferHammarström `tac` is nice for static files, but if I do something like `tail -f -s 0.1 /var/log/apache2/error.log | sed -r '1,/\[notice\]/d'` then I can't use it.

Comment: @Kent Not specifically for this question, but I do work with an disk frugal embedded system where the catch all scripting tool is `sed`: having good `sed` chops in general (for me) is handy.

Comment: @Jamie: If you do that, how do you know which occurrence of `[notice]` is the last?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/\[notice\]/{h;d};x;/./!{x;d};x;H;$!d;x;s/[^\n]*\n//' file
```

Store the pattern and the lines thereafter in the hold space. At end of file print these lines out (former itterations of the pattern are over written by the last).

An alternative way, is to slurp the whole file into memory and then delete the parts not needed (greed is your friend :):

```
sed ':a;$!{N;ba};s/.*\[notice\][^\n]*\n//' file
```

Answer (score 2):

sed is an excellent tool for simple substitutions in a single line, for any other text manipulation just use awk:

```
$ cat file
line 1
[notice]
line 2
[notice]
line 3

$ awk 'NR==FNR{if (/\[notice\]/) tgt=NR; next} FNR>tgt' file file
line 3
```

The above uses 2 passes of the file, the first pass to find the line number of the last occurrence of the pattern and the second pass to print the lines you want.

An alternative would be to read the whole file as a single record and then get rid of everything up until the last [notice] (and surrounding spaces/newlines), e.g. with GNU awk:

```
$ gawk -v RS='\0' -v ORS= '{sub(/.*\[notice\]\s*/,"")}1' file
line 3
```

Comment: Thanks for responding; I should've mentioned that the input file is streaming so multiple passes is challenging.  No?

Comment: It's not challenging, it's impossible. How can you identify the last occurrence of a pattern in a stream?

Comment: By buffering the data since the last occurence: one might end up reading the whole file into memory, but it could be done with a single pass.  Potong's answer hints at that although I didn't quite work for me.

Comment: You just said it's not a file, it's a stream. You can't tell when you find the **last** RE in a stream because the next line you receive in the stream might contain that same RE.

Answer (score 0):

Read file once, might be bad for large files

```sh
awk '{a[NR]=$0; /notice/ && b=NR} END {for(c=b+1;c<=NR;c++) print a[c]}'
```